# How I stop multi booking on same time?

Tags: java, android

> I getting booking details from `firebase firestore` and set into Recyclerview by bean(DTO) class there i have time and date value in integer I wanna stop multi booking in same time or near 30 mints anyone tell me how can I stop it..??

Main `Recyclerview Fragement` There I getting value by firestore

```
RecyclerView listView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    lbean = new ArrayList<>();
    sheduleAdapter= new SheduleAdapter(getActivity(),lbean);

    listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    listView.setAdapter(sheduleAdapter);




    db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error:" + e.getMessage());
            }
            for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                switch (doc.getType()) {
                    case ADDED:
                        bean = doc.getDocument().toObject(bean.class);
                        lbean.add(bean);
                        sheduleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case MODIFIED:
                        bean = doc.getDocument().toObject(bean.class);
                        lbean.add(bean);
                        sheduleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case REMOVED:
                        lbean.remove(bean);
                        sheduleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Recyclerview Adapter there i set value from bean class

```
        holder.mint.setText(String.valueOf(bean.get(position).getMint()));
    holder.hour.setText(String.valueOf(bean.get(position).getHour()));
    holder.day.setText(String.valueOf(bean.get(position).getDay()));
    holder.month.setText(String.valueOf(bean.get(position).getMonth()));
    holder.year.setText(String.valueOf(bean.get(position).getYear()));


    holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();

            iHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            iMin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE );
            iYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            iMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            iDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            iMin=bean.get(position).getMint();
            iHour=bean.get(position).getHour();
            iDay=bean.get(position).getDay();
            iMonth=bean.get(position).getMonth();
            iYear=bean.get(position).getYear();

            c.set(iYear,iMonth,iDay,iHour,iMin);

                    String mm = String.valueOf(iMin);
                    String h = String.valueOf(iHour);
                    String d = String.valueOf(iDay);
                    String m = String.valueOf(iMonth);
                    String y = String.valueOf(iYear);


                    Toast.makeText(context, mm + "==" + h + "==" + d + "==" + m + "==" + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


                    DocumentReference ref = db.collection("users").document();
                    final String myId = ref.getId();
                    Toast.makeText(context, myId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               }
    });

}
```

Comment: You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).